# Flutter Instantiate object on Startup

Tags: flutter, dart, startup

I am building an app which displays results it reads from a .json file. In that app I have a header-object, which stores the is the "table of contents"-object. In that object I have a list of other objects which are the results I want to display. I tried to just instantiate that object whenever I opened that page with calling `Header().results.map(...);`, but IMHO this is extremely dodgy and inelegant. When I tried to instantiate the object with `var ToC = new Header();` before `runApp(myApp);` as follows:

```
void main() {
  var ToC = new Header();
  print(ToC);
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: MyTabs(),
    ),
  );
}
```

but when running `ToC.results.map((result) => MeasCard(result: result)).toList()` in the Dart file that should generate the List I just got the error message:

> Undefined name 'ToC'

How do I instantiate such an object on app startup? Or is there another method to call the constructor just once?

Comment: Can you please put your main file where you tried to call runApp, and what is the error message that you got ?

Comment: Added the parts of the files that were important

Comment: Add WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); as first line to the main method

Comment: Ok, it shifted the problem. Now it tells me: "The getter ToC isn't defined for the Class '_ResultListState' when I try to run it

Comment: show us the code of _ResultListState

Comment: `class _ResultListState extends State<ResultList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      body: Column(
          children: ToC.results.map((result) => MeasCard(result: result)).toList());
  }
}`

Comment: And please post your comment also as answer so I can acccept it and give you credit for it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210925/discussion-between-ikerfah-and-vincent-guttmann).

Comment: make the Toc to toc, use lower case

Comment: didn't work, still the same error